# How can I display CP437 charsets?

Tags: html, character-encoding

Does anyone knows how I can display CP437 charsets? For example the chars ▒ and ░ ?
I tried to just say in the html meta tag:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;" charset=CP437">
```

But there I didn't saw any of the characters above.

Comment: You've got a `"` after the `html;`, which terminates the `content` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two separate issues. One is about using the CP437 *character encoding* for an HTML document. Character encodings are often called “charsets” even in official protocols. The answer is that in principle you can use CP437, but in practice it hardly ever pays off.

A correct tag to declare CP437 is

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=IBM437">
```

or, simpler,

```
<meta charset=IBM437>
```

In the first syntax, note the use of quotation marks. The preferred MIME name for CP437 is IBM437, according to the [IANA registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml). This is just a matter of principle; in practice, the name CP437 works just as well, or as poorly.

(Note: Any such `meta` tag can be overridden by an HTTP header or by a UTF-8 BOM at the start of the actual data. There is nothing you can do in HTML to such things.)

On the practical side, tested in modern browsers on Win 7, only IE supports CP437. Both Firefox and Chrome fall back to their default encoding, in my case windows-1252. This means that the bytes will be interpreted in a completely different way.

The other issue is whether you can the *characters* that can be represented in CP437. The answer is emphatically yes: all those characters are Unicode characters, and you can [use them like any other characters](http://www.cs.tut.fi/%7Ejkorpela/html/characters.html), either as such in a widely supported encoding, in practice UTF-8, or using character references, which work independently of character encoding. Example:

```html
<p>▒ and ░ (the characters as such)</p>
<p>&#x2592; and &#x2591; (using hexadecimal references)</p>
<p>&#9618; and &#9617; (using decimal references)</p>
```

There is readable but non-authoritative information about CP437 to Unicode mapping in the [Wikipedia page on CP437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437). I’m afraid I can’t give a really authoritative reference, but the IANA registry refers to [RFC 1345](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1345), even though it is informational only.